# Run NSTimer from a background task

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to use a `NSTimer` as a background task. I've written this code:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
        UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        }];
        self.silenceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(findlocation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

But it doesn't fire the `findlocation` method after 30 seconds. Please guide me how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make my App run an NSTimer in the background?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220494/how-do-i-make-my-app-run-an-nstimer-in-the-background)

Comment: Try this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656214/iphone-backgrounding-to-poll-for-events

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
 dispatch_source_t timerSource = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, backgroundQueue);
 dispatch_source_set_timer(timerSource, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0), 10.0*NSEC_PER_SEC, 0*NSEC_PER_SEC);
 dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timerSource, ^{
     if(queue)
         [self findlocation];
 });
 dispatch_resume(timerSource);
```

Comment: where can i mention 30 seconds and what is queue

Comment: here queue is a bool. Set its value to true

Comment: If i writw like this then that method will be called for every 30 seconds.I don't want like that,i need to call for first time only.

Comment: set queue=FALSE in findlocation

Comment: Everytime it will be called that method suddenly after run this code.NOt waiting that 30 seconds

Comment: if you want to run only one time then why not you directly use NSTimer?

Comment: [self findlocation]; is never fired

Answer (score 0):

`NSTimer` are paused when the app is in background state.

You'll have to start some background task to do what you want. But even with that, you will be limited to a certain amount of time after the app was put in background.

Real backgrounding behavior is only granted for location tracking, VoIP or Audio apps. Other apps must face limitations: once in background, you are given an amount of time to complete tasks you start with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: (`backgroundTimeRemaining`)`.

Check this for more information http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

For a clean solution, check the accepted answer of this question [How do I make my App run an NSTimer in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9220494/how-do-i-make-my-app-run-an-nstimer-in-the-background)

Comment: before using the timer on that thread, i am using the CLLocationmanager

Comment: @KevinChar check the answer in the link, similar situation like yours. right?

Comment: Iam already called the startlocationupdatingmethod before start the timer.

Answer (score 0):

This code to play the sound when application enter into background you can customize it for your own use

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application{
    backgroundTask = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    }];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
        [self startPlayingInBackground:@"default.aif"];
        NSLog(@"Time remaining: %f",[application backgroundTimeRemaining]);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
            {
                // if you don't call endBackgroundTask, the OS will exit your app.
                [application endBackgroundTask:backgroundTask];
                backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

The line below is the code with help of which m playing the sound it's my objective c function all

```
[self startPlayingInBackground:@"default.aif"];
```

[reference from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704430/can-i-use-nstimer-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
    UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
    }];
    self.silenceTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30 target:self selector:@selector(findlocation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

[[NSRunloop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.silenceTimer forMode:NSDEfaultRunLoopMode];